# Include more space for multiple plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fit 6 plots into the same plot chunk using the R packages `cowplot` and `ggplot2`. But my grand title and two of my plots keep getting cut off, and I am not sure how to change the margins of the overall plot chunk.

I don't necessarily need to use the `cowplot` package.

Here is some dummy data:

```
library("cowplot")
library("ggplot2")

##grab a segment of the mtcars dataframe and assign that segment to an object
mtcars.one <- mtcars[1:21,]
mtcars.two <- mtcars[11:32,]
mtcars.three <- mtcars[5:26,]
mtcars.four <- mtcars[7:28,]
mtcars.five <- mtcars[4:25,]
mtcars.six <- mtcars[9:30,]

#using ggplot2 package, create a barplot where the coordinates are flipped, give the axes labels and overall plot a title, and assign plot to an object
one.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.one) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.one), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings") 

two.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.two) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.two), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

three.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.three) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.three), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

four.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.four) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.four), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

five.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.five) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.five), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

six.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.six) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.six), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")
```

Here is where I am putting the 6 plots together, and here is where I think I am missing something in terms of specifying the overall size of my plotting area:

```
#plot each of my 6 plots so there are two columns and three rows, where the width and height of all plots are 0.5 inches
ggdraw()+
    draw_plot(one.f, x=0, y=1.0, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    draw_plot(two.f, x=.5, y=1.0, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    draw_plot(three.f, x=0, y=0.5, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    draw_plot(four.f, x=0.5, y=0.5, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    draw_plot(five.f, x=0, y=0, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    draw_plot(six.f, x=0.5, y=0, width=0.5, height=0.5)+
    #add letter labels (A-F) to the upper-left corner of each plot
    draw_plot_label(label=LETTERS[1:6], 
         x=c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5), y=c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), fontface='bold')
#include an overall title that describes all 6 plots together
title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("Loadings for Cars in mtcars", fontface='bold')
```

Here is the output from the code I provided, and here you can see two of the six plots are missing as well as my grand title:

[image]

My actual data have 21 values, where in my example are the "Cars", so I cannot squish the plots too much or my 21 values are indistinguishable, as you can see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone comes up with a better answer, instead of using the package `cowplot` I can use `ggpubr`, which has a function called `ggarrange`. This function allows me to plot on multiple pages, which in practical use doesn't actually extend to additional pages I am just able to extend my plotting area without distorting the multiple plots within my grand plot.

Here is my code using the dummy data from the question to plot all 6 plots on the same page without distortion:

```
library(ggpubr)
multi.page <- ggpubr::ggarrange(one.f, two.f, three.f, four.f, five.f, six.f, 
                                nrow = 3, ncol = 2) +
                      draw_plot_label(label=LETTERS[1:6], 
                           x=c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5), 
                           y=c(1, 1, 0.667, 0.667, 0.335, 0.335))
ggexport(multi.page, filename = "This is my file name.pdf")
```

And here is what the final plot looks like:
[image]

I have not figured out where I can fit my grand title, which may not be necessary for publishing in a journal, because I can always add a caption to my figure.

Also, the "Cars" labels are still squished, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

One option can be using `patchwork` and avoid the overlap of labels in the final plot using `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))` and playing with the font size:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
##grab a segment of the mtcars dataframe and assign that segment to an object
mtcars.one <- mtcars[1:21,]
mtcars.two <- mtcars[11:32,]
mtcars.three <- mtcars[5:26,]
mtcars.four <- mtcars[7:28,]
mtcars.five <- mtcars[4:25,]
mtcars.six <- mtcars[9:30,]

#using ggplot2 package, create a barplot where the coordinates are flipped, give the axes labels and overall plot a title, and assign plot to an object
one.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.one) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.one), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings") 

two.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.two) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.two), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

three.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.three) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.three), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

four.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.four) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.four), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

five.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.five) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.five), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

six.f <- ggplot(data = mtcars.six) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x= rownames(mtcars.six), y=disp)) + 
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="Cars", y="Loadings", title = "These Loadings")

#Plot
Out <- wrap_plots(list(one.f,two.f,three.f,four.f,five.f,six.f),ncol = 2)+
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = c('A'))&theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=7))&
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Plot 2
Out2 <- wrap_plots(list(one.f,two.f,three.f,four.f,five.f,six.f),ncol = 2)+
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = c('A'))+
  plot_layout(widths = c(0.5, 1))&theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=7))&
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I changed n.dodge to 1, so I would only have the Cars labeled once. I am not certain I understand what the scale_x_discrete function does? Your code works great to get all 6 plots on the same grand plot. However, each of the 6 plots are stretched horizontally, and in this patchwork package can I add a title for the whole thing?

Comment: @simpson Yeah you can try adding at the end `&ggtitle('My title')`

Comment: any idea how to explicitly choose the size of each of the 6 plots using that patchwork package you suggested? Or how to un-stretch the 6 plots?

Comment: @simpson I have added an update. Play around `plot_layout(widths = c(0.5, 1))` which allows you tuning the size! I hope that helps you!